# Setting up the Structure of a Polynomial

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to evaluate the structure of a polynomial by simply listing the coefficients and displaying them with a variable with its respected power.  I'm not evaluating, I'm just trying to get the equation out there.

```
public class TestPolynomialBackup{
    public static void main(String[] args){


        Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(4);

        System.out.println(p1);

    }



    public static class Polynomial
    {
        private int[] coef;
        private int power=3;

        public Polynomial(int a ){
            coef = new int []{4,3,2,1};
        }



        public String toString() {

           for(int i=0;i<coef.length-1;i++){
               String s = coef[2] + "x^" + power;
                return s;
           }

        }



     }
}
```

Output:      TestPolynomialBackup.java:38: error: missing return statement
         }

I keep getting that error at the toString() method.  All i'm trying to do is to make a for-loop that will go down the array of coefficents with some conditions that will determine if the character "x" (variable) will appear as well as the power.

Comment: Your toString() is nonsense, which is why it doesn't compile.  You need to return outside the loop as well, but even if you did that, it wouldn't do something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna get more familiar with Java and think about what you **want** this method to do:

```
public String toString() {
    for (int i = 0; i < coef.length - 1; i++) {
        String s = coef[2] + "x^" + power;
        return s;
    }
}
```

This is propably what you want:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < coef.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            s.append(" + ");
        s.append(coef[i]);
        s.append("x^");
        s.append(i);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Changes:

- put `return` outside of loop
- **accumulate** result instead of somehow always creating a new string
- actually use your index `i` inside of the loop
- let the loop go from `0` to `coef.length - 1`
- added `" + "` as a delimiter

Comment: Actually you'll want to use a `StringBuilder` instead of creating new Strings all the time.

Comment: indeed, just wanted to emphasise correct semantics first ;) especially this does not look perf-critical at all - editing...

Comment: Thanks olydis.  I've been away from java for months and I've forgotten most of it.  This practice is strictly for school.  I've also added some conditions within the loop that will determine how String s prints out.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a return after your for loop.

The compiler can't compile because if your loop is not executed, your method would return nothing.

But you should review the way your loop is working, since you have a return in it, it is executed only once.